# grep command for a text file in multiple directories

Tags: command-line, grep, text-processing

I have 24 directories in a specific directory (main_directory). Each 24 directory have a text file whose name is DATA.txt.

I need to use grep command to extract below specific pattern for each text file;

```
2* x  = 3800689.6402     y  = 882077.3636     z  = 5028791.2953
```

`2* x  =` part is constant for all DATA.txt. The other numeric numbers are variable. I need to extract above line for each DATA.txt and save them into another text file. Which script I can use for this process?

Comment: Just `grep -FR '2* x' main_directory > another_text_file`?

Comment: @muru this code search all text files in directories so it works very slow. How can I restrict the search only DATA.txt file.

Comment: Add `--include=DATA.txt`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To recursively search using `grep`, use the `-R` option.

To search for an exact string, use `-F`, so that `2*` isn't treated as a regular expression.

To search only on specific filenames, use the `--include` option. Combined:

```
grep -FR --include=DATA.txt '2* x' main_directory > another_text_file
```

Comment: @guru each directory name consist of numbers like, 0001 0102 0203 ...2324. Is there a way to greping these directories w.r.t. the number orders? (i.e, grep 0001, 0102, 0203, 0304........2324 and append the results into text file with that order). Above command greping random.

Comment: @deepblue_86 not for grep itself. The above command would have the file paths in the output, so sort it: `grep … | sort -f: -k1,1 > another_text_file`

Comment: alright @muru, it is oked.

Answer (score 5):

Since you know the name of the target files, you can also do

```
grep '^2\* x' */DATA.txt > newfile
```

Or, with `awk`:

```
awk '^/2\* x/' */DATA.txt > newfile
```

And Perl:

```
perl -ne 'print if /2\* x/' */DATA.txt > newfile
```

Answer (score 1):

General approach:

```
grep -r <pattern>
```

or

specific approach:

```
find -name <file patterns which you want to find> | xargs grep <pattern you looking for>
```

Comment: The `find` approach will fail if any file names or their paths contain spaces or newlines .

Comment: who use newlines in file names? My find search for filenames with spaces. It's problem with xargs - it needs additional argument for files with blank spaces.

Comment: Some people choose to, other times it happens by accident. The main point is that newlines are allowed in file names so it is good practice to consider them. And yes, `find` can deal with both spaces and newlines and anything else. Which is why `find -name foo -exec grep bar {} +` is better than `xargs` but, if you want to use `xargs`, you need to do `find -name foo -print0 | xargs -0 grep bar`.